# MediaPlayer replays when other MediaPlayer starts

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-recyclerview

So in my program I have a recyclerview with a series of buttons and when a button is clicked it should play a sound file. But if there are any other sounds playing it should stop them first and play the current sound.

However, when I select one and quickly select another one it will replay the first one and then play the second one.

Edit: so im noticing that when the first one replays, it stops relatively quickly, so it doesnt play the entire file, but it still starts

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    for(MediaPlayer player : mediaPlayerList){
                        if(player.isPlaying()){
                            player.pause();
                            player.seekTo(0);
                        }
                    }

                    mediaPlayerList.get(position).start();

                }
            })
    );
}
```

Everything works fine, its just the first sound selected plays twice for some odd reason, I placed a pause() and seekTo(0) so that it would stop it and allow it to be replayed from the beginning

Im not sure if this is related but I am also getting a logcat error :  getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab80f170.

MediaplayerList contains

```
final List<MediaPlayer> mediaPlayerList = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
        mediaPlayerList.add(0,mediaPlayer0);mediaPlayerList.add(1,mediaPlayer1);
        mediaPlayerList.add(2,mediaPlayer2);mediaPlayerList.add(3,mediaPlayer3);
        mediaPlayerList.add(4,mediaPlayer4);mediaPlayerList.add(5,mediaPlayer5);
```

each MediaPlayer

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer0 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing player.pause() if a song is already playing and you select another song, you need to stop and reset the media player like

Instead of

```
player.pause();
player.seekTo(0);
```

Do

```
player.stop();
player.reset();
```

**Edit:** Try doing something like this. Make a global media player object like

```
private MediaPlayer player;
```

Then for playing the song do

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
        new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                if(player.isPlaying()){
                     player.stop();
                     player.reset();
                }
                player = mediaPlayerList.get(position);
                player.start();
            }
```

**Edit 2:** OK try this

```
recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.meme_list);
adapter = new Adapter(this,getData());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) { 
            player.start();  
        }
});
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                       if (player.isPlaying())
                       {
                           player.stop();
                           player.reset();

                       }


                    player= mediaPlayerList.get(position);
                    player.prepare();

                }
            })
    );
```

Comment: After about 8 different starts, im getting logcat errors saying "start called in state 1", "error (-38, 0)"

Comment: i can select other files, but then they too eventually stop working and producing the same error

Comment: You also need to setDataSource and call player.prepare() before you start the media player

Comment: Check out the activity cycle of media player in android here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html . The data source in the media player will not be cleared when you stop the media player. For clearing the previous song's data source you need to call reset()

Comment: is there an alternative to setDataSource? the data source is determined based on which list item is clicked.

Comment: Does your mediaPlayerList contain the Uri of the song?

Comment: Can you show me how you are playing the first song? and what mediaPlayerList actually contains?

Comment: I updated the post, im not sure what you mean by how i am playing the first song.  It starts when clicked from the recyclerview

Comment: player.prepare() is highlighted red as for unhandled IO excpetion

Comment: Actually get rid of prepare() since you are using create to start music you don't need to use prepare()

Comment: player returned a fatal null pointer exception, i tried adding a for each loop to fix it but resulted with the same problem

Comment: Did you create new MediaPlayer? Like private MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

Comment: fixed that, and reverted back to what you suggested.  Still getting error (-38,0)

Comment: based on the flow chart from the android reference it seems to me that setDataSource() -> prepare() is the only way... would there be a way to get the data source within the method?

Comment: Or could prepare async be used and then from there onpreparedlistenere.onprepared

Comment: You can use create for raw files. I think I need your full code bro. setDatasource() is needed if you have the song uri. And when you use setDatasource() you need prepare()

Comment: how can i send this to you? i could maybe email?

Comment: Post the entire class where you are doing anything with mediaPlayer here itself

Comment: posted the entire class

Comment: After a sound is played more than once it produces these errors:
 E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0
 E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)

Comment: What does it say on the logcat?

Comment: E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0
error (-38,0)

Comment: player.prepare() is still being highlighted as an unhandled IO exception

Comment: I used a try catch statement, but it produced a fatal exception, prepare() is causing issues

Comment: Try to be descriptive please, what issues?

Comment: It seems as if player.prepare() can not be used with player.setDataSource

Comment: Fatal exception on main, IllegalStateException with prepare()